# React-Native convert a base64 images array to a single pdf

Tags: image, pdf, react-native, base64

I'm working on a mobile app in react-native / redux in which I have to convert an array of base64 images into a pdf in order to send the pdf to the back-end.
Any idea about how to achieve it ?

Comment: see if this helps get you where you're going https://medium.com/@dschmidt1992/rebuilding-a-pdf-form-with-react-native-9718e7419c2c

Comment: Thanks for the link, I found a solution just before to see your comment ;)

Comment: I solved this issue in this another [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69738812/problem-to-generate-pdf-from-a-blob-in-an-expo-app-using-filesystem)

Answer (score 3):

Ok I finally found an easy solution with the help of [react-native-image-to-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-to-pdf)
It is promis based. In a file I called "pdfConverter.js" I created this function

```
import RNImageToPdf from "react-native-image-to-pdf";

export default base64Arr => {
  // It is a promise based function
  // Create an array containing the path of each base64 images
  let base64Paths = [];
  base64Paths.length = 0; // re-initialize the array for further re-use

  base64Arr.forEach(base64 => {
    base64Paths.push(`data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64}`);
  });

  // Convert base64 images to pdf from the paths array
  return RNImageToPdf.createPDFbyImages({
    imagePaths: base64Paths,
    name: "PDF_Name"
  });
};
```

and then call it where I need in another file :

```
import toPDF from "./pdfConverter.js";

toPDF(myBase64array)
.then(pdf => {
  console.log("pdf ", pdf);
});
```

Comment: cool, you might want to fling a github star at the author to show some love. he's only got 1 star so far https://github.com/JonasLaux/react-native-image-to-pdf

Comment: great, especially since he only published 3 days ago. Just in the nick of time for your needs :D. I'm sure he won't mind the encouragement.

Comment: Haha ! Perfect timing

Comment: nothing going happen here  mergeImage(){
        RNImageToPdf.createPDFbyImages({
            imagePaths: this.state.myarr,
            name: "PDF_Name"
        }).then(pdf => {
            console.log("pdf ", pdf);
        }).catch(err => console.log("error catch search:", err));
    }

Comment: Anyone looking into it ?