# Problem to generate pdf from a blob in an expo app using FileSystem

Tags: react-native, expo, pdf-generation, blob, filereader

I get a blob and I treat it like this:

```
const file = response.data;
  var blob = new Blob([file], {
    type: 'application/pdf',
  });

  const fileReaderInstance = new FileReader();
  fileReaderInstance.readAsDataURL(blob);
  fileReaderInstance.onload = async () => {
    const fileUri = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}file.pdf`;
    await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(
      fileUri,
      fileReaderInstance.result.split(',')[1],
      {
        encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
      }
    );
    console.log(fileUri);
    Sharing.shareAsync(fileUri);
  };
```

however when I generate and share the file, I can't access it and if I get its URI and search on the web it returns:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved my problem in this way:

This is a func who get other data to request, do the request (`generate PDF()`) and treat the data and generate by received blob the buffer on (`fileReaderInstance.result`) who is shared in `Sharing.shareAsync()`

```
  const generatePDF = async () => {
    setAnimating(true);
    const companyReponse = await CompanyService.getCompany();
    const peopleResponse = await PeopleService.getPerson(sale.customerId);

    const company = companyReponse.response.company;
    const people = peopleResponse.response;
    const quote = false;

    const json = await SaleService.generatePDF({
      sale,
      company,
      people,
      quote,
    });

    if (json && json.success) {
      try {
        const fileReaderInstance = new FileReader();
        fileReaderInstance.readAsDataURL(json.data);
        fileReaderInstance.onload = async () => {
          const base64data = fileReaderInstance.result.split(',');
          const pdfBuffer = base64data[1];

          const path = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}/${sale._id}.pdf`;
          await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(`${path}`, pdfBuffer, {
            encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
          });

          await Sharing.shareAsync(path, { mimeType: 'application/pdf' });
        };
      } catch (error) {
        Alert.alert('Erro ao gerar o PDF', error.message);
      }
    }
    setAnimating(false);
  }
```

This is the func in SaleService`generatePDF` who do the request to api and pass the parameters that return a blob of pdf using axios:

```
 generatePDF: async ({ sale, company, people, quote }) => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    const body = { sale, company, people, quote };
    try {
      const response = await axios(`${BASE_API}/generate-sale-pdf`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: token,
        },
        responseType: 'blob',
        data: body,
      });

      return {
        success: true,
        data: response.data,
      };
    } catch (err) {
      return err.error;
    }
  },
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this worked very well for me! Splitting the format out of the base64 string and then adding it into the Sharing.shareAsync(). Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by passing the blob string to **WriteAsStringAsync** method of **FileSystem** library from expo.

```
const blobDat = data.data[0].data; //blob data coming from an API call
const fileUri = FileSystem.documentDirectory + `testt.pdf`; //Directory Link of the file to be saved
await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(fileUri, blobDat, {
  encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.UTF8,
}) //This step writes the blob string to the pdf fileURI
await IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync("android.intent.action.VIEW", {
  data: fileUri,
  flags: 1,
  type: "application/pdf",
});
//prompts user with available application to open the above created pdf.
```