# Manipulate base64 file in expo

Tags: react-native, base64, expo, pdf-generation

I need to manipulate this file I get in Base64 (download it or share it):

```
const generatePDF = async () => {
    const companyReponse = await CompanyService.getCompany();
    const peopleResponse = await PeopleService.getPerson(sale.customerId);

    const company = companyReponse.response.company;
    const people = peopleResponse.response;
    const quote = false;

    const json = await SaleService.generatePDF({
      sale,
      company,
      people,
      quote,
    });

    await ensureFolderExists();

    if (json && json.success) {
      const path = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}MyFolder/Sale_${sale._id}.pdf`;

      await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(path, json.data, {
        encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
      });

      const url = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}MyFolder/Sale_${sale._id}.pdf`;

      Linking.openURL(url);
    }
  };
```

using the base64 string returns and searching like this in the browser `data:application/pdf;base64,${json.data}` I can even see it. but I've tried it in several ways and none of them worked, I believe this one may be closer to success.

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Could not open URL 'file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/ExperienceData/%2540sensiogabriel%252FSensio/MyFolder/Sale_61a122679719d630dc416f91.pdf': file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/ExperienceData/%2540sensiogabriel%252FSensio/MyFolder/Sale_61a122679719d630dc416f91.pdf exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue in this another [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69738812/problem-to-generate-pdf-from-a-blob-in-an-expo-app-using-filesystem)